# Sync with active table Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In Visual Studio you have a function: sync with active document. This is a very handy function. Because you can see in the solution explorer where the document has been stored.

My question is: is there a similar function in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - that you can stand with your cursor on the table name in a query and then for example with a sub menu you can see witch table is selected in the object explorer.

This is especially handy if you have for example 300 tables and you want to see the columns of that table that you have written in a query.

THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to do this natively in SQL Server Management Studio. However, there are several third party extensions which do have this feature.

Two of the more popular extensions:

1. [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) (free)
2. [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) (paid w/free trial)

Both of these tools have functionality that allows you to navigate to an object in the Object Explorer, or view the contents of the object from within the query window by hovering the mouse over the object name.

For example, this can be accomplished in ApexSQL Complete by right-clicking an object and selecting "Navigate to object".

Comment: There's even a video showing how it works in SQL Prompt, which also works in Visual Studio as well as SSMS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3pcNG8b6g8

Comment: There is also a free add-in, SQL Search (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/), from Redgate, that will let you quickly search for an object and see where this exists in Object Explorer.

AFAIK, as noted by soukai, there isn't a native way to do this.

Disclosure, I work for Redgate Software.